# Is it bad practice to pass a "string" or boolean as a parameter in JS?

Tags: javascript, parameters

If I call a function with something like the following instead of using variables is that bad practice?

```
canIPass("strings", true);
```

I believe that in my code I was causing some infinite loop but than in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nb5B/) it seems to work fine.

I looked around but haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: *"...instead of using variables is that bad practice."* Is ***what*** bad practice? This question makes no sense. (I haven't looked at the fiddle as questions must stand on their own.)

Comment: Definitely passing literals instead of variables to a function won't cause an infinitive loop. Rather you seem to have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/202792) with your question. Please post the actual code causing troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine, you can pass anything you want, event functions, this is the beauty of javascript !

Comment: Thanks htatche and spass :)

Answer (score 1):

No that's perfectly fine. Post the code that gave you an infinite loop so maybe we can help you with that.